# Asked to attend overview meetings before a firm offer has been made by potential employer

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, negotiation, employment-agreement

I am looking for advice/best practice on how to handle discussions and negotiations with a potential employer.

I've been in discussions to take a role with a potential employer. The discussions have been extremely positive and very strong indications of interest is being shown by the potential employer. An offer, however, is yet to be put on the table by the potential employer. As a next step, I've been asked to meet group heads for an overview of the businesses.

1. At this stage, can I approach the potential employer and ask for a formal offer before meeting the group heads?

or,

2. Meet the group heads for the overview and then wait for the offer?

Would appreciate feedback on the best way to go forward towards a positive outcome.

Comment: They asked for the meeting before giving you the offer. Does that tell you anything other than they want the meeting before giving you the offer? Why do you think asking for the offer would be a good idea at this stage?

Comment: To me this would be classified as a form of non-technical interview.  I would strongly recommend treating it as such.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to just attend the meeting before getting the offer?

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend waiting.

In most cases, candidates have very small windows into the actual day to day work that the job entails. They accept an offer with an expectation of what they will be doing, but what they actually will be doing is different.

You have the opportunity observe and meet with dept. heads before you are even hired.

If you make an outstanding impression, you have more information about the job and reputation with company stakeholders to negotiate with in the final offer.

Comment: It's quite possible that they will formulate an offer based on the outcome of the meeting with the department heads.  So very definitely the correct course of action is to go through with the meeting, ensure you engage with them professionally then see what falls out of it.